# Should I use dns name or API gateway generated url for lambda who is calling API gateway internally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am deploying API gateway and Lambda functions on AWS. The API gateway has an auto generated endpoint url. And I have a domain name managed by Route53 DNS which points to the gateway URL. One of my lambda needs to send requests to the API gateway in the same AWS region. My question is that should I use the auto-generated API gateway endpoint or DNS domain name in my labmda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both but there are some points that you can consider where DNS is better in term of changes aws resources.

- By using DNS you've more flexibility like if you made changes API gateway and the endpoint change because of some reason you don't need to update code, all you need to update route53 record to point new API gateway endpoint as a result no change will be required on code and lambda will request to the new endpoint.
- You can update DNS during maintenance and still no changes will be required in the code side, there can be many options as DNS gives you flexibility.

During DNS configuration make sure you are using aliases for AWS endpoint as AWS **redirect queries to selected AWS resources**, unlike CNAME where redirect **DNS queries to any DNS record**.

[resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)

Comment: Does DNS give me any latency?

Comment: Yes a bit you can verify this using `time dig cname.example.com` and `time dig alias.example.com`